# GIS data visualization

Tags: geolocation, graph, time-series, visualisation

I have a huge data set with geolocation information. I am trying to visualize the data but the tools cannot handle such a big graph. Size of the file is about 5GB and has more than 3 million rows.

What is the best way to visualize the time-series and geolocation based data?

I have a CSV and I did try using online tools like CartoDB, Plotly and did try using ArcGIS but that is commercial tool.

I got stuck as the file is too big and the tools won't allow loading the files. It is a social network data with spatio-temporal information. I used gepi, cytoscape, ScoNet, Tupil, Anaconda GraphViz but nothing would even load the file. The same if I use sample 10 rows it would work good.

Comment: What tools?  What type of file?

Comment: @PolyGeo Edited the question

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad and seeks opinions. Choosing one tool, what precisely did you try and where precisely did you get stuck?

Comment: I got stuck as the file is too big and the tools wont allow loading the files. It is a social network data with spatiotemporal information. I used gepi, cytoscape, ScoNet, Tupil, Anaconda GraphViz but nothing would even load the file. The same If I use sample 10 rows it would work good.

Comment: For focused Q&A please provide a specific example (i.e. tool and syntax, or code snippet, and a few sample records), so that we know precisely one thing that you tried and got stuck on.

Comment: I agree with PolyGeo. We need more info. However, just a shot in the dark; have you looked at D3.js to use with your CSV?

Comment: I agree with both of you about precise problem..  Well my precise problem is to visualise huge dataset with about 5 million nodes.. I mentioned in comment as well I can very well visualize if I take 10 or 100 nodes..  But when I am giving the entire dataset the mentioned tools crash and when tried with python would get low memory error..  Unless I cannot load my input for starters how can write about error which have not shown yet..

Comment: Comments do not form part of your question. Their purpose is simply to help you clarify it.

Comment: Please do not add new information to the comments. Instead, [Edit] the question. It is not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.